# Why doesn't my xib file do anything in Xcode 5?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode5, xib

I am new here. I am making a Cocoa application in "xcode 5.1.1". I don't understand why my controls don't show up when they are on my `xib`. I also tried with an empty app. But It works with the pref pane. Am I missing something here?

All I did is drag a button on. Then I connected an `IBOutlet` to it.

Comment: A little more details are welcome.

Comment: What about some code about the connections you made betweend the .h and the nib file?! And maybe a screenshot. Nobody can help you if you don't give us enough information.

Comment: I am currently on a mobile device... I will though. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an autolayout issue but who knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will the Application load your xib file at all? Maybe you set your project to start with a completly different user interface. Change the background color of your xib and check if this color will be shown in the running application.

The startup user interface can be changed in the project settings / project editor in Xcode.